# When is it not possible to apply vectorization to pandas processing?

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, vectorization

I understand this might be a paricularly ambiguous question, but I have been experimenting with optimizing code using pandas vectorization because I work with Bigdata.
I also understand the basic idea of vectorization, that if a function can operate on an array as a whole without having to consider the individual elements of the array then it can be used in vectorization. I want to understand if it is at all possible to apply vectorization in cases where the parameters to a function are lists,dicts etc. when there are conditions on the elements of the data in the structure.

Let me give a basic example:
suppossing I have a function that takes a python list, maps the elements of this list to values in another. Then performs an operation like jaccard similarity between the mapped list and a third list.

Would vectorization be possible, or it is only possible with a sequential function like pandas.dataframe.apply()?

Comment: Hi Jonathan, maybe you want to add a concrete example of what you want to achieve, with some sample data and code, then people will be able to help you. Otherwise your question is probably too generic.

Comment: @divingTobi sorry, yes it is a pretty generic question and I won't mind a generic answer. What I want to do is already implemented with df.apply() which is still pretty slow. When I look into vectorization, it's not clear in what cases it can't be used. If the question is too generic to answer then I understand and will take it down.